# Decode 11-bit numbers from set of 8 bit numbers

Tags: c, binary, decode, bit

How can I decode 16 11-bit numbers from 22 bytes?

This is the description from the data sheet.

> **Payload:**
>
> - 11 bits Channel 1
> - 11 bits Channel 2
> - ...
> - 11 bits Channel 16
>
> 16 channels packed into 22 bytes

My C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        // There are 16 11-bit channels encoded in these 22 numbers.

        // Example data
        /* NEW INFORMATION
           This data arrived from a serial connection
           420,000 baud
           non-inverted
           8 bit
           1 stop
           Big Endian*/
        int data[22] = {224,11,223,47,194,199,10,86,176,130,21,192,0,6,48,128,1,62,240,129,15,124};

        int channels[16] = 0;

        // decode and set each channel

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Choose a language, C or C++.

Comment: Time to use a bitmask and lots of bit shifting.

Comment: You might want to also note how it is getting into memory; you may need to do some byte swapping as well.

Comment: You may want to consider writing this function in assembly language.  Most assembly languages have instructions specific for bit twiddling.

Comment: Picture contents:
Payload
  11bits Channel 1
  ...
  11bits Channel 16
16 channels packed into 22 bytes

Comment: What kind of hardware device is this?  Other devices, like DAC and ADC will either shift the bits out (SPI interface) or be directly connected to the address bus (so that you can read 11 bits with a 16-bit fetch).  Nothing unusual like packing 22 bits.

Comment: This is a TBS Crossfire Nano RX.  This is the "channels" portion of one of the CRSF frames.

Comment: What's the layout? Does `data[0]` contain the 8 least or most significant bits of a number?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're working one byte at a time from left to right like this:

```
|               0               |               1               |               2               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                           0               |               1                           |  ...
```

You would need to perform the following shifts:

```
int i,j;
for (i=0,j=0; i<16; i+=8,j+=11) {
   channels[i+0] = ((data[j+0] & 0xFF) << 3)  | ((data[j+1] & 0xE0) >> 5);
   channels[i+1] = ((data[j+1] & 0x1F) << 6)  | ((data[j+2] & 0xFA) >> 2);
   channels[i+2] = ((data[j+2] & 0x03) << 9)  | ((data[j+3] & 0xFF) << 1) | ((data[j+4] & 0x80) >> 7);
   channels[i+3] = ((data[j+4] & 0x7F) << 4)  | ((data[j+5] & 0xF0) >> 4);
   channels[i+4] = ((data[j+5] & 0x0F) << 7)  | ((data[j+6] & 0xFE) >> 1);
   channels[i+5] = ((data[j+6] & 0x01) << 10) | ((data[j+7] & 0xFF) << 1) | ((data[j+8] & 0xA0) >> 6);
   channels[i+6] = ((data[j+8] & 0x3F) << 5)  | ((data[j+9] & 0xF8) >> 3);
   channels[i+7] = ((data[j+9] & 0x07) << 8)  | ((data[j+10] & 0xFF) >> 0);
}
```

With groups of 11 bits, you need to go through 8 groups of 11 to end on a whole byte before the cycle repeats, so here we do it twice for 16 groups

Comment: @P__J__ is correct.  The incoming data (example data in the code) should be unsigned char, not int.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your array with data to decode has to `unsigned char` not `int`

Here is a function (not tested as it is a bit too late) to extract the particular value)

```
#define mask   ((1 << 12) - 1)

unsigned getval(unsigned char *array, int pos)
{
    int bitpos = pos * 11;
    int byte = pos / 8;
    int startbyte;
    int startbit = 0;
    uint32_t buff;

    if(byte + 4 > 21) 
    { 
        startbyte = 21 - 4;
        startbit = (byte - startbyte) * 8;
    }
    else
    {
        startbyte = byte;
    }

    startbit += bitpos & 7;
    memcpy(&buff, array + startbyte, sizeof(buff));
    buff &= mask << startbit;
    buff >>= startbit;

    return buff;
}
```

assumpions: little endian

Comment: Further information I found regarding the serial connection.  
420000 baud
non-inverted
8 bit
1 Stop
Big Endian

I think your solution is nearly correct (I say nearly because of the "little endian" part.  which I am not sure how to change)